# Фильтрация списка

Tags: android, listview

В приложении есть `ListView`. Нужно отфильтровать этот список с помощью другого списка. То есть item'ы из другого списка - это параметры фильтрования первого списка.
Фильтрация первого списка делается с помощью `multiple choice`.

`list_ch` - список, с помощью которого нужно отфильтровать первый список.
Подскажите советом.

Вот код с отображением другого списка, нажатые items отображаются в `Next_activity`.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView lvMain;
    Button btnChecked;
    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById();


        String[] List_ch =
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_CH);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, List_ch);
        lvMain.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnChecked.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void findViewById() {
        lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        btnChecked = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChecked);


    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
            SparseBooleanArray checked = lvMain.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList < String > selectedItems = new ArrayList < String > ();
            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                int position = checked.keyAt(i);

                if (checked.valueAt(i))
                    selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));


            }
            String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);

            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Next_activity.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

            intent.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(intent);
```

**Next_activity**

```
public class Next_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Checked);

            ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resultArr);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```